# jetty security realm static content

Tags: security, jetty, jdbcrealm

jetty 9

setting up a context xml to serve static html, which is dynamically generated at the end of various CI processes

I set up a hashlogin realm in the jetty.xml as follows

```xml
<Call name="addBean">
<Arg>
  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
    <Set name="name">Test Realm</Set>
    <Set name="config">E:/jimmy/http/jetty-distribution-9.2.10.v20150310/etc/realm.properties</Set> 
  </New>
</Arg>
</Call>
```

then in the context.xml I do this

context path:  `/jimmyndepend`

```xml
<Get name="securityHandler">

 <Set name="loginService">
  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
        <Set name="name">Test Realm</Set>
        <Set name="config">/etc/realm.properties</Set>
  </New>
</Set>
</Get>
```

Set name="resourceBase" E:/jimmy/html

the realm is like this:

guest: guest

However when starting jetty, I can browse to the context /jimmyndepend and I am not prompted for a user/password.

Can I do this without a web.xml?

Thanks